# Getting the error " net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: No session ID" while trying to execute the scripts

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

Script was working successfully till last week and all of a sudden I got the below error from this week onwards. Please advise.

```
net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: The following error occurred: No active session with ID b324bd213592fbdc663589a2beae51da (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:38959}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 68.0.3440.84, webStorageEnabled: true, webdriver.remote.sessionid: b324bd213592fbdc663589a2bea...}
Session ID: b324bd213592fbdc663589a2beae51da
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.throwNoSuchElementExceptionWithCauseIfPresent(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:893)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.checkPresenceOfWebElement(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:866)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.waitUntilVisible(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:873)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.thucydides.core.annotations.locators.AbstractSingleItemHandler.invoke(AbstractSingleItemHandler.java:45)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.waitUntilVisible(Unknown Source)
    at pageobjects.portfolio.PortfolioEpic.SelectPortfolioFromNav(PortfolioEpic.java:139)
    at steps.portfolio.EndUser_Portfolio.OpenPortfolioSection(EndUser_Portfolio.java:15)
    at steps.portfolio.EndUser_Portfolio$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b8cc665a.CGLIB$OpenPortfolioSection$19(<generated>)
    at steps.portfolio.EndUser_Portfolio$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b8cc665a$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d9213826.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(StepInterceptor.java:426)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(StepInterceptor.java:411)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:386)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:134)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:63)
    at steps.portfolio.EndUser_Portfolio$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b8cc665a.OpenPortfolioSection(<generated>)
    at stepdefs.portfolio.PortfolioStepDefs.iAmOnPortfolioLandingPageOnMyAssetsViewContainer(PortfolioStepDefs.java:23)
    at ?.I am on Portfolio landing page on My Assets view container(C:/Workspace/bitbucket/stockbroking-website-rewrite-fe/src/test/resources/features/portfolio/Portfolio_AddRemoveColumns.feature:17)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: No active session with ID b324bd213592fbdc663589a2beae51da (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:38959}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 68.0.3440.84, webStorageEnabled: true, webdriver.remote.sessionid: b324bd213592fbdc663589a2bea...}
Session ID: b324bd213592fbdc663589a2beae51da
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:834)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.setTimeouts(WebDriverFactory.java:200)
    at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.setImplicitTimeout(WebDriverFacade.java:298)
    at net.thucydides.core.annotations.locators.SmartAjaxElementLocator.findElementImmediately(SmartAjaxElementLocator.java:141)
    at net.thucydides.core.annotations.locators.SmartAjaxElementLocator.findElement(SmartAjaxElementLocator.java:123)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementResolverByElementLocator.resolveForDriver(WebElementResolverByElementLocator.java:27)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.getElement(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:209)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.isVisible(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:393)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.isCurrentlyVisible(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:429)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementExpectations$1.apply(WebElementExpectations.java:23)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementExpectations$1.apply(WebElementExpectations.java:15)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.checkPresenceOfWebElement(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:860)
    at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl.waitUntilVisible(WebElementFacadeImpl.java:873)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.thucydides.core.annotations.locators.AbstractSingleItemHandler.invoke(AbstractSingleItemHandler.java:45)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.waitUntilVisible(Unknown Source)
    at pageobjects.portfolio.PortfolioEpic.SelectPortfolioFromNav(PortfolioEpic.java:139)
    at steps.portfolio.EndUser_Portfolio.OpenPortfolioSection(EndUser_Portfolio.java:15)
    at steps.portfolio.EndUser_Portfolio$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b8cc665a.CGLIB$OpenPortfolioSection$19(<generated>)
    at steps.portfolio.EndUser_Portfolio$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b8cc665a$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d9213826.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(StepInterceptor.java:426)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(StepInterceptor.java:411)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:386)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:134)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:63)
    at steps.portfolio.EndUser_Portfolio$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b8cc665a.OpenPortfolioSection(<generated>)
    at stepdefs.portfolio.PortfolioStepDefs.iAmOnPortfolioLandingPageOnMyAssetsViewContainer(PortfolioStepDefs.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:32)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
    at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
    at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:99)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:108)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:369)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)

[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 147.985 s <<< FAILURE! - in nedbank.co.za.stockbrokingfrontend.Parallel01IT
[ERROR] Add or Remove Columns(Portfolio: Add and Remove Portfolio columns)  Time elapsed: 69.392 s  <<< ERROR!
net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: 
The following error occurred: No active session with ID 954142e5ec5eb760b3b9b51f56620489 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:41634}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 68.0.3440.84, webStorageEnabled: true, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 954142e5ec5eb760b3b9b51f566...}
Session ID: 954142e5ec5eb760b3b9b51f56620489
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: 
No active session with ID 954142e5ec5eb760b3b9b51f56620489 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:41634}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 68.0.3440.84, webStorageEnabled: true, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 954142e5ec5eb760b3b9b51f566...}
Session ID: 954142e5ec5eb760b3b9b51f56620489
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: The following error occurred: No active session with ID b324bd213592fbdc663589a2beae51da (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
```

...implies that the *WebDriver* was unable to communicate with the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *`java.version: '1.8.0_161'`*
- But you are using *Selenium version: `'3.7.1`'* of *2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z* which is old and ancient.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

Comment: Thanks @Dehanjan. However it didn't work. Getting the same issue even after upgrading the selenium version.

Comment: @Renju Missed out to mention about JDK version. Checkout the updated answer.

Comment: @Renju Let us discuss this in [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium).